It is possible to find all Mobile & Lightning Actions that are enabled for a particular Publisher Layout
We want to deprecate certain Global Actions that are registered for one or more Publisher Layouts.
By providing our customers a list of all Publisher Layouts where a certain Mobile & Lightning Actions is enabled, it makes it possible to easily trace them and remove them.
Through the ToolingAPI I know it's possible to retrieve information about all Publisher Layouts by making a httpRequest with endpoint like below:
String endpoint = '/services/data/v58.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+FullName+FROM+Layout+WHERE+LayoutType=%27GlobalQuickActionList%27'

This however gives no information about what Mobile & Lightning Actions are enabled for this Publisher Layout.
Is it possible to retrieve information about what Mobile & Lightning Actions are enabled for a particular Publisher Layout?
For clarity, below image shows actions Post, File, New Task, ... etc. under section: Salesforce Mobile & Lightning Experience Actions, these actions should be retrieved through any possible route. Help would be appreciated, thanks.


The endpoint I used is only useful to retrieve basic information about the publisher layout.
When endpoint '/services/data/v58.0/tooling/sobjects/layout/yourLayoutId' is used to retrieve al information about the layout.
So I used the first endpoint to retrieve all Id's of global layouts and used these Id's to setup the other endpoint.
